# Method under @test not works, untill placed with the url

Tags: browser-automation

`@Test method is not working, but works when placed after flipkart url section.`
i think that if i place the click function with url then it will be a wrong approach, code should be independent.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class Testdemo {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void test2() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");    
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.className("_29YdH8")).click();
    }
}
```

**java.lang.NullPointerException
   at Test.Flipkart.data(Flipkart.java:40)**

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that even though you defined a class level variable for driver as below

```
public class Testdemo {
    WebDriver driver;
```

You never initiated , because in  @BeforeTest you defined it as a local variable again
So it throws null point excepption for the driver, To solve this please remove webdriver , so the class level variable will be used

```
**WebDriver** driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

Corrected code

```
 @BeforeTest
    public void test2() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I got the mistake and i will never repeat it. i am a fresher to this so that is why this happens. Thanks again. I will ask for help again!!!

Comment: Could you please help me, by giving me few conditions for which i can write the script!